# Cannot create shared object of protobuf with android g++ standalone compiler

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile protobuf with the android arm g++ as a shared object, however the compiler is only outputting static objects.    Here's the error in the configure step:

> checking whether the
>   /opt/build-android-linux/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
>   linker
>   (/opt/build-android-linux/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld)
>   supports shared libraries... no

Here's my environment for executing the configure step

export NDK="/home/john/Development/android-ndk-r8e/"

export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm

export CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI --sysroot=$SYSROOT"

export CPPFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
androideabi/lib/ -lgnustl_shared"

export CC="/opt/build-android-linux/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"

export CXX="/opt/build-android-linux/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"

export AR="/opt/build-android-linux/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"

./configure --host=arm-eabi --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT CC=$CC --enable-cross-compile --with-protoc=protoc --enable-static=false

Thanks in advance